# Can I make a C++ method in external assembly (function.asm)?

Tags: c++, assembly, methods, member-functions

I am writing a program that requires one function in assembly. It would be pretty helpful to encapsulate the assembly function in a C++ class, so its own data is isolated and I can create multiple instances.

If I create a class and call an external function from a C++ method, the function is reentrant even if it has its own stack and local "variables" into the stack frame.

Is there some way to make the assembly function a C++ method, maybe using name mangling, so the function is implemented in assembly but the prototype is declared inside the C++ class?

If not possible, is there some way to create multiple instances (dynamically) of the assembly function although it is not part of the class? Something like clone the function in memory and just call it, obviously using relocatable code (adding a delta displacement for variables and data if required)...

Comment: You seem to throw a lot of words around but not have a point. What concrete use case does a free function not cover?

Comment: Why does it *require one function in assembly*? That seems pretty unlikely.

Comment: Probably easier to write the class in `C++` and add inline assembly to the member function that needs it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.  Either define it as an inline wrapper that passes all the args (including the implicit `this` pointer) to an external function, or figure out the name-mangling to define the right symbol for the function entry point in asm.

An example of the wrapper way:

```
extern "C" int asm_function(myclass *p, int a, double b);

class myclass {

    int q, r, member_array[4];
    int my_method(int a, double b) { return asm_function(this, a, b); }
};
```

A stand-alone definition of `my_method` for x86-64 would be just `jmp asm_function`, a tailcall, because the args are identical.  So after inlining, you'll have `call asm_function` instead of `call _Zmyclass_mymethodZd`  or whatever the actual name mangling is.  (I made that up).

---

In GNU C / C++, there's also the [`asm` keyword to set the asm symbol name for a function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels), instead of letting the normal name-mangling rules generate it from the class and member-function name, and arg types.  (Or with extern "C", usually just a leading underscore or not, depending on the platform.)

```
class myclass {
    int q, r, member_array[4];
  public:
    int my_method(int a, double b) 
      asm("myclass_my_method_int_double");  // symbol name for separate asm
};
```

Then in your .asm file (e.g. NASM syntax, for the x86-64 System V calling convention)

```
global myclass_my_method_int_double
myclass_my_method_int_double:
;; inputs: myclass *this  in  RDI,  int a  in ESI,  double b  in XMM0
   cvtsd2si eax, xmm0
   add      eax, [rdi+4]  ;; this->r
   imul     eax, esi
   ret
```

(You can pick any name you want for your asm function; it doesn't *have* to encode the args.  But doing that will let you overload it without conflicting symbol names.)

Example [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/b5dz43cv1) of a test caller calling the asm("") way:

```
void foo(myclass *p){
    p->my_method(1, 1.0);
}
```

compiles to

```
foo(myclass*):
        movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # xmm0 = mem[0],zero
        mov     esi, 1
        jmp     myclass_my_method_int_double    # TAILCALL
```

Note that the caller emitted `jmp     myclass_my_method_int_double`, using your name, not a mangled name.

Answer (score 3):

> I am writing a program that requires one function in assembly.

Then, by definition, your program becomes much less [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting). And depends upon the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) of your C++ implementation and your operating system.

It would then be coherent to use some compiler specific features (which are not in portable standard C++11, e.g. in [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)).

My recommendation is then to take advantage of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) extended assembly. Read the chapter on [using assembly language with C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) (it also, and of course, applies to C++).

By directly embedding some extended `asm` inside a C++ member function, you avoid the hassle of *calling* some function. Probably, your assembler code is really short and executed quickly. So it is better to embed it in C or C++ functions, avoiding the costs of function call prologue and epilogue.

NB: In 2019, there is no economical sense to spend efforts in writing large assembly code: most optimizing compilers produce better assembler code than a reasonable programmer can (in a reasonable time). So you have an incentive to use *small* assembler code chunks in larger C++ or C functions.